# How to find model year of this Honda Shadow bike 'NC34-1002157'?

Tags: honda, motorcycle

Recently, I was about buying nice Honda Shadow but the seller didn't know the model year of his bike. I saw many 17-digit vin numbers and I can decode it, but 11-digit vin is difficult and I don't know how to get model year from it.

I know `N=400, C=Street, 34=Internal production..' But Where is model year? How to find the model year ? 
I searched over 2 days, I found some links, but didn't helped me.
Thanks

VIN = NC34-1002157

Comment: Everything I find online says that motorcycles should have 17-digit VINs just like cars. Could it be that you've found some other part id code or serial number, and the VIN is somewhere else on the bike?

Comment: Some internet comments suggest the VIN is on the neck, and you may have to turn the handlebars or remove a plastic neck cover to see it.

Comment: @NateEldredge: Yes, I also heard that it's only 17-digit, but after researching I found that from 80's till end of 90's I thing till 95 or 97  Honda was 11-digit,  But after that changed to 17-digit.

Comment: Even in the 80's Honda motorcycles had a 17 digit VIN.  VIN is on the steering head of the frame.  The tenth character represents the year the motorcycle was made and is typically represented by a letter.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a VIN number untangler from the Honda website.

http://automobiles.honda.com/information/frequently-asked-questions.aspx?Question=20

Since your the one with the VIN and haven't posted it you will have to untangle it yourself.

Best of luck

Comment: I wouldn't recommend anyone share their VIN online

Comment: @zaid  It's not the full VIN.  Just the beginning portion where other global information is formatted into it.

Answer (score 0):

I realise this is perhaps 3 years late for the OP but as another user has had the same query I may as well post for their benefit it's a 1997 - the 11 digit code is the "frame number" and NC34-100XXXX format ones are for a [1997 Shadow NV400](http://bikeswiki.com/Honda_VT400_Shadow_(NV400))